# Por qué en la consola de JavaScript se visualizan las funciones "por fuera" y por dentro también del constructor?

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo sobre JavaScript y tengo una duda en como se visualizan los prototipos en la consola de JavaScript del navegador.
En el siguiente ejemplo:

```
function iPhone() {} // constructor
iPhone.prototype.faceID = function () {
  face: "método";
}; // un método para reconocer rostros
iPhone.prototype.video = function () {
  video: "método";
}; // un método para tomar video 4k
let newPhone = new iPhone(); // un iPhone 11
console.log(newPhone);
```

En la consola se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si __*proto* es una propiedad de la instancia y prototype es una propiedad del constructor ¿Por qué las funciones se muestran también "por fuera" del prototype del constructor? ¿Es una cuestión de visualización?

Comment: No, no es una cuestión de visualización. La programación Orientada a Objetos, tal como la entiendes o comprendes desde otros lenguajes, no puedes aplicarla al pie de la letra en Javascript por una sencilla razón: la herencia en Javascript se basa en prototipos. Dicho esto, lo que en principio se podría considerar una Clase (distinta de una instancia de la misma, o sea un Objeto) no es más que azúcar sintáctico para definir una función. Es decir, en Javascript (ES2015 en adelante) podemos usar la palabra `Class` como una forma amigable (hacia OOP) para escribir una función. Saludos

Comment: Y, qué dice google? Hay mucha investigación detrás de esto. Mira [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711). También vale la pena revisar [este otro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes). Puedes compartir lo que tú investigaste, porfa?